# How to call Recursive function for array data Using Promises in Node Js

Tags: node.js, recursion, promise

I am trying to call the recursive function in my code. The loop executing first time, but recursive function which is called inside the function is not working.
Here is my code :

```
function buildDynamicMenu(elements,parentId)
{
 branch =new Array();
 elements.forEach(function(element){

    if (element['parent_id'] == parentId) {
       children =  buildDynamicMenu(elements, element['menu_id']); //Recursive function not working
       if (children) {
            element['children'] =children;

        }
        branch = element;

    } 
    });
    return branch;

}
 var parentId=0;
 buildDynamicMenu(data); // Array data
```

I have added sample array which I am using for this logic, array has menu and Submenu Id,  we have to call recursive function to loop through all sub  array

```
 Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [menu_id] => 1
        [menu_name] => Home
        [parent_id] => 0
        [link] => #home
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [menu_id] => 2
        [menu_name] => Web development
        [parent_id] => 0
        [link] => #web-dev
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [menu_id] => 3
        [menu_name] => WordPress Development
        [parent_id] => 2
        [link] => #wp-dev
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [menu_id] => 4
        [menu_name] => About w3school.info
        [parent_id] => 2
        [link] => #w3school-info
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [menu_id] => 7
        [menu_name] => Javascript
        [parent_id] => 2
        [link] => #
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [menu_id] => 8
        [menu_name] => Plugins
        [parent_id] => 7
        [link] => #plugin-dev
    )
)
```

Comment: I see 2 problems, First parentId is set to 0 during your actual method call (do you intend to do that?), Second, the recursive call sends the data array again, which starts from index 0 (creating an infinite loop, you might want to slice and send it).

Comment: you need to pass parentId when calling function, that is buildDynamicMenu(data, parentId);

Comment: I am passing menu Id as parent Id, if any sub  menu records are there for that id , it should loop, In PHP I am getting proper values including all child records. I want to convert  that into node Js

Comment: Can anyone tell me , how to use the Promise  for recursive call for above effort.

Comment: @Monica is right. You need to supply a parentId on your first function invoke, otherwise `if (element['parent_id'] == parentId)` branch will never be entered, because `parentId` is `undefined` and I presume no elements have `parent_id` set to `undefined`. Or, rewrite your function.

Comment: @user3829086 you can use async await https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: @user3829086 can you share sample data ?

Comment: @user3829086 branch =new Array(); outside the function.I think there is no issue with the recursion .your code is overwriting the variable branch

Comment: @Monica , I have added sample array which I am using.Please suggest me how to loop in recursive call?

Answer (score 0):

seems like this doesn't have a pointed buildDynamicMenu export. check if there is one in 'this'. try to assign the buildDynamicMenu function to some const and perform call to it.

Ok here is my demo func working very well in nodejs typescript:

```
function recursieve (p) {
console.log('in recursieve ', p);
if (p > 0) {
    recursieve (--p);
} } recursieve (10);// rec call
```

So in my opinion there are two problems in your code:
1. 'this' was not pointed to the function.
2. recursieve condition, like the elements is empty, or id is no match.

Comment: I have removed 'this' and tried. Same  issue , It is not taking recursive function. Every time it will call that buildDynamicMenu  function , but nothing has stored in children array.